# Ключ шифрования не подходит

Tags: java, android, криптография

Загружаю ключ из памяти телефона, декодирую из  `base64` в `byte`, получаю ключ и дальше уже работаю с ним. Но при запуске программа выдает ошибку

> unknown key type passed to RSA.

Что я делаю не правильно?

```
void main1() throws LoginException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
          String test = "hello";
          Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
         //key
         byte [] decodedPublicKey = Base64.decode(myPublickKey, 4);
         byte[] decodedPrivateKey = Base64.decode(myPrivateKey,4);

         SecretKey originalPublicKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedPublicKey, 0, decodedPublicKey.length, "RSA");
         SecretKeySpec originalPrivateKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedPrivateKey, 0, decodedPrivateKey.length, "RSA");


          cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalPublicKey);

        byte[] bytes2 = cipher2.doFinal(test.getBytes());

       Cipher decript2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");


         decript2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,originalPrivateKey);

      byte[] decriptedBytes2 = decript2.doFinal(bytes2);

       for (byte b : decriptedBytes2)kodMess+=(char) b;

         Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, kodMess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
```

Кодирую так

```
//генерирую ключ 
        KeyPairGenerator pairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = pairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Key publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        Key privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
//ключи в строку 
        final String encodedPublicKey = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(),0);
        final String encodedPrivateKey = Base64.encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded(),0);
//обратно в байты
       byte [] decodedPublicKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey, 0);
       byte[] decodedPrivateKey = Base64.decode(encodedPrivateKey,0);
//из байт в ключи
        SecretKey   originalPublicKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedPublicKey, 0, decodedPublicKey.length, "RSA");
        SecretKey   originalPrivateKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedPrivateKey, 0, decodedPrivateKey.length, "RSA");
```

Comment: А вы приватный и публичный ключи, часом, не путаете?

Comment: Я попробовал поменять их местами, результат не изменился

Comment: Значит, непонятный формат ключа :-)

Comment: Я примерно тоже самое делал с методом шифрования AES, все сработало

Comment: Ключ для AES примерно в 4+ раза короче и проще, чем ключ для RSA.

Comment: Надо бы сравнить оригинальный ключ(до кодировки) с раскодированным. Как-то смущает флаг 4 - при кодировании Вы тоже его используете? Если да, попробуйте заменить на 0.

Comment: Не, это не помогло, может я как то неправильно преобразовываю байты в ключ

Comment: я сравнил ключи до и после. До сохранения был огромный ключ, как и должно быть а после, строка - javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@b0

Comment: Покажите как кодируете.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте как в коде ниже. Дело в том, что конструкторы `SecretKeySpec` не знают ничего о внутреннем формате ключей. Для этого нужно использовать `X509EncodedKeySpec` и `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`:

```
KeyPairGenerator pairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
KeyPair keyPair = pairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
Key publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
Key privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

final byte[] encodedPublicKeyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(publicKey.getEncoded());
final byte[] encodedPrivateKeyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(privateKey.getEncoded());

final String encPubKey = new String(encodedPublicKeyBytes);
final String encPrivKey = new String(encodedPrivateKeyBytes);

System.out.println(encPubKey);
System.out.println(encPrivKey);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
byte[] decPubKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPublicKeyBytes);
X509EncodedKeySpec X509pubKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decPubKey);
PublicKey pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(X509pubKey);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
byte[] rsaEncrypted = cipher.doFinal("test-test-test".getBytes());

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
byte[] decPrivKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPrivateKeyBytes);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decPrivKey);
PrivateKey privKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
byte[] rsaDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(rsaEncrypted);

System.out.println(new String(rsaDecrypted));
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо